# Ionic Native BLE - No callbacks

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use [Ionic Native BLE](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/) on Ionic 3, but none of its functions return any callbacks, not even when subscribed. I am testing [this example](https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples/tree/master/scan) on a 7.0 android device. I am not forgetting to turn on the location and the bluetooth.

First, I thought that the problem was in the Ionic Native itself, but I tested the File functions and it worked fine, so I am lost. It has been a month now since I have been trying everything to make this work and nothing works.

Comment: you're going to have to do better than "it doesn't work" ... I've used the thing you're asking about but I can't begin to suggest an answer based on the information you've provided. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I'm sorry for the incomplete question but I also don't understand the error completely. But, let's say that I have a function to find BLE devices (called scan()). This function has 2 functions inside the subscribe(), one for a success (generating a list of devices) and one for an error (generating a toast). So, the problem is that the functions inside the subscribe are never called, so I don't get any callbacks. And this example happens with all the other BLE functions.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to solve it, at last. All I had to do was to deploy the apk using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/). I was using the debug version of the apk and it never called the BLE options. I wish that this could work for the debug version as well.